# If $x+y+z=\pi$, prove that $\cot(x)\cot(y)+\cot(y)\cot(z)+\cot(x)\cot(z)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've gotten to the point where I've expanded the left hand expression to:

$\frac{\sin(z)\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\cos(y)\cos(z)+\sin(y)\cos(x)\cos(z)}{\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z)}$

I'd imagine that perhaps we're supposed to turn the trig functions into those for a single variable, and I've tried:

$\frac{\sin(z)\frac{1}{2}(\cos(x+y)-\sin(x-y))+\sin(x)\frac{1}{2}(\cos(y+z)-\sin(y-z))+\sin(y))\frac{1}{2}(\cos(x+z)-\sin(x-z))}{\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z)}$

$\frac{\sin(z)\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\pi-z)-\sin(\pi-y-2z))+\sin(x)\frac{1}{2}(\cos(y+z)-\sin(y-z))+\sin(y))\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\pi-y)-\sin(\pi-y-2z))}{\sin(\pi-y-z)\sin(y)\sin(z)}$

But that hasn't worked out for me either.

I need your help.

Comment: $$\cot(x)\cot(y)+\cot(x)\cot(z)+\cot(y)\cot(z)=\cot(x)\cot(y)-\cot(x+y)\left[\cot(x)+\cot(y)\right]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea with turning the trig functions into ones in a single variable, but there's a nicer way: combine the first two terms on the top first.

$$ \begin{align}
& \frac{\sin(z)\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\cos(y)\cos(z)+\sin(y)\cos(x)\cos(z)}{\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z)} \\ &= \frac{\cos(y)\Big[\sin(z)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(z)\Big]+\sin(y)\cos(x)\cos(z)}{\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z)} \\
&= \frac{\cos(y)\Big[\sin(x+z)\Big]+\sin(y)\cos(x)\cos(z)}{\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z)}  \\
&= \frac{\cos(y)\Big[\sin(\pi - y)\Big]+\sin(y)\cos(x)\cos(z)}{\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z)} \\
&= \frac{\cos(y)\sin(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)\cos(z)}{\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(z)} \\
&= \frac{\cos(y)+\cos(x)\cos(z)}{\sin(x)\sin(z)} \\
&= \frac{-\cos(x+z)+\cos(x)\cos(z)}{\sin(x)\sin(z)} \\
\end{align} $$
Then one more application of trig identities finishes it off nicely.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin(x+y+z)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the addition formulea for sin & cos.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(x) \cos(y)\sin(z)+\cos(x) \sin(y)\cos(z)+\sin(x) \cos(y)\cos(z)-\sin(x) \sin(y)\sin(z)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do a little algebra !

Answer (score 1):

You know that $z=\pi-(x+y)$, so
$$
\cot z=\cot(\pi-(x+y))=-\cot(x+y)=-\frac{\cot x\cot y-1}{\cot x+\cot y}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your identity is wrong of course. Try $x=y=0$ and $z=\pi$.